# Windshield Wiper Transmission Linkage Bushings for 2002 Civic EX (1.7L L4)

Tags: windshield-wipers, diy

I have the factory windshield wiper transmission installed on my Honda, and now the wiper is "slapping" on the cowl which is extremely annoying.  Researching, I've found that it may be possible to just replace the bushings on the linkages to fix the issue.  **My question is, does anyone know what bushings I can buy to replace the worn out bushings?**  I'm trying to avoid having to buy the entire wiper transmission.  There are many results to bushings that I can buy, but I do not know which ones would be compatible.

- [Dorman Wiper Transmission](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00NF1UNNK)
- [RockAuto Wiper Transmissions](http://www.rockauto.com/en/catalog/honda,2002,civic,1.7l+l4,1386277,wiper+&+washer,wiper+linkage+/+transmission,8856)

Answer (score 1):

This site has individual parts.

https://www.hondapartsnow.com/parts-list/2002-honda-civic-4dr_dx-ka-4at/front-wiper.html?PNC=14

I've replaced just the 2 arms (10 and 11 on the diagram) on my 94 integra.  Not sure if you need to get any bushings (like 7 or 8) with that.

You might a just need new bushings from an assortment pack like the following:
[https://www.amazon.com/Dorman-49447-Windshield-Linkage-Assortment/dp/B000IWFPIW/ref=pd_sbs_263_1?_encoding=UTF8&pd_rd_i=B000IWFPIW&pd_rd_r=P2A7ZPWQQDWQR69F9MRD&pd_rd_w=1BkKV&pd_rd_wg=ZGg8r&psc=1&refRID=P2A7ZPWQQDWQR69F9MRD](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000IWFPIW)
hard to guarantee it would fit thought